# How to get two images and a textview to all have the same height in a bar and fill the entire width?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create a menu header with one image on the left, another on the right, and the title in the middle.  The title is rather long so it needs to wrap the text.

I'm trying to get it so that the two images, which are of different sizes, scale to a small square and then have the text fill in the center space.  I also want to use RelativeLayout and not TableLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_MenuHeader_Left"
        android:src="@drawable/iu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/square_menus"  
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/square_menus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView_MenuHeader_Right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_MenuHeader_Right"
        android:src="@drawable/iu2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/square_menus"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HelpTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/square_menus"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:text="@string/help_title"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/ImageView_MenuHeader_Right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ImageView_MenuHeader_Left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ImageView_MenuHeader_Right"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_title_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Right now what this code is producing is the right image doesn't look like a square, the width is larger than the height. The bottom of the left image is also higher than the textview, where I really want all of them to be the same height so all three look like a bar at the top.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> the right image doesn't look like a square, the width is larger than the height.

add `android:maxHeight="@dimen/square_menus"` for the right `ImageView`

> The bottom of the left image is also higher than the textview

add `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView_MenuHeader_Leftt"` to the `TextView`

You might wanna consider changing the layout :-)

Comment: I think I already had the maxHeight in the right ImageView.  I also added the alignBottom but it didn't help.  :(  What would you suggest as the layout I should use?